# When is __lldb_init_module called?

Tags: python, objective-c, ios, llvm, lldb

I'm following WWDC session 412 - Debugging in Xcode. There is a demo there about creating custom LLDB summaries for your own classes.

I simply can't get the summaries to show up.

By inserting print calls in the Python script I have been able to determine that:

1. The script file is getting imported
2. __lldb_init_module is never called

Any idea about what could prevent __lldb_init_module from being called? Is there a specific time when you need to import the script?

Comment: Yes! I had the exact same issue but sadly I have no insight on the matter. +1 for empathy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me this worked by adding

```
command script import /path/to/CustomSummaries.py
```

to the `~/.lldbinit` file and restarting Xcode, or by setting a breakpoint in "main" and executing the import command in the debugger console.

I tested it with a minimal custom description script:

```
import lldb

def myobject_summary(valueObject, dictionary):

    return 'MyCustomDescription'

def __lldb_init_module(debugger, dict):

    debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add MyObject -F CustomSummaries.myobject_summary')
```

and this is the view in the Xcode debugger window:

[image]

Note that you have to restart Xcode after changes to the script. It also seems that the output of "print" statements in the init method is not shown if the script is imported in the Xcode debugger console.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR but I can't find a ~/.lldbinit path on my mac for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: @Stavash: `~/.lldbinit` means `.lldbinit` in the home directory, e.g. `/Users/stavash/.lldbinit`. This file does not exist by default, you will have to create it.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks again. @MihaiDamian please check this out for yourself and consider accepting this answer

Comment: Works. Didn't count on Xcode having to be restarted after I change the script.